# jQuery user activity logging

Tags: jquery, logging, focus, blur

I want to log user activity.
According other users response on StackOverflow I made a small jQuery library:

```
var stop_timeout = false;
$(window).blur(function(){
    elvis('left the building since ');
}).focus(function(){
    elvis('come back now:');
}).mousemove(function() {
    zima();
}).keyup(function() {
    zima();
});

function elvis(ce) {
    var now=new Date();
    $('.showMe').append('Elvis ' + ce + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() +':'+now.getSeconds()+'<br>');
}

function zima() {
   clearTimeout(stop_timeout);
   stop_timeout = setTimeout(function() {
       $('.showMe').append('No activity since 10 seconds...<br>');
   }, 10000);
}
```

and html:

```
<input type="text" size="20"> 
<div class="showMe"></div>
```

The code is working Ok and, obviously, the mousemove and keyup events fires even I blur or focus on window.
What I need is to fire mousemove and keyup ONLY on $(window).focus()

Thank you !

Edit: Also I made a Jfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6RLBQ/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `keyup event` should be trigger to your `input element` like,

```
$('input').keyup(function () {
    zima();
});
```

**Full code**

```
var stop_timeout = false;

$(document).blur(function () {
    elvis('left the building since ');
}).focus(function () {
    elvis('come back now:');
}).mousemove(function () {
    zima();
});

$('input').keyup(function () {
    zima();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Kumar, but is not about input element, because I want to construct some generic logging function, and not some particularized. Also it's about mousemove event. I try right now to set some var keys on window.focus() event to be true and check on mousemove and keyup...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question, guys. I believe I get it now. 
mousemove() and keyup() is binding by default to $(window) and it's firing only on window focus. Question close !